# Xpages: ExtLib V12: Application Layout with Bootstrap Configuration. Collapsible left column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using the Application Layout Control with the bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration.
The nsf is running on an 9.0.1FP2 server and i'm using the latest Extension Library version v12.
The source looks like this:

```
...
<xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
        <xp:callback
            facetName="facetMiddle"
            id="facetMiddle">
        </xp:callback>
        <xe:this.facets>
            <xp:callback
                facetName="facetLeft"
                id="facetLeft"
                xp:key="LeftColumn">
            </xp:callback>
            <xp:callback
                facetName="facetRight"
                id="facetRight"
                xp:key="RightColumn">
            </xp:callback>
        </xe:this.facets>
        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration invertedNavbar="true"
                collapseLeftColumn="true" productLogoAlt="SelfService"
                placeBar="false" footer="false" legal="false" pageWidth="fluid"
                fixedNavbar="fixed-top">
...
```

The result is: if I resize the window on the desktop or view the page on a mobile device, the left column is hidden (as expected).

But unfortunately I do not get a handle to access to the Left Column. I expect a Menu button, or something similar.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did it not turn the menu into a hamburger?  That is the three horizontal bars in the upper right?

Comment: nope, unfortunately not. The App-Menu/Hamburger/banner only displays the entries that I've configured as application links

Comment: I would say there *has* to be a way to configure that but I don't know it. My guess it that someone here will know this fairly soon.

Comment: I heard there was a bug somewhere in the Application Layout for bootstrap.  I THOUGHT it was for the NavBar...  but I could be wrong.  Since the navBar is broken out into it's own control I personally would avoid the AppLayoutControl and make my own cc_layout that has whatever grid I went as well as a navBar.  That's been working well for me.

Comment: I also think that this is a bug. I only wonder that so far none has yet noticed. I will report it also as an issue  at github and openntf. And in the meantime i will try your proposal. Thx @david

Comment: I suspect that most people really wanting to get into XPages and bootstrap are skipping the App Layout Control just so they gain better control over what they want to do.  That's my approach at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'collapsible left menu' feature will only work if you have a menu in the left column of your application layout that (in the generated HTML) contains a list of menu options using the `<ul>` tag (as is common in a Bootstrap layout). I just tried it with just this in my left column:

```
<ul>
  <li>Menu option 1</li>
  <li>Menu option 2</li>
</ul>
```

and it worked: it automatically created a button in my layout with the default label 'Menu' (can be changed using the `collapseLeftMenuLabel` property). The button is only visible on small screens and opens a popup menu showing the menu options you created.

You can create the menu by writing HTML in the XPages, or by adding an `<xe:navigator>` control to the left column: that will also create a `<ul><li>` structure in the generated HTML.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Mark! With the navigator-control I made it! Now I will try to bring my stuff in a <ul><li>-structure. I had thought that it works no matter which content. At the end i'll probably follow the suggestion of David, and build me my own layout-control, because I would like to make the left column available at swipe-right and the right column at swipe-left.